# HTML button call on jQuery/Javascript to display a dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

so I am not proficient in programming by any means, I just know enough Javascript, HTML, and CSS to be dangerous and I'm wicked good at googling (except in this case). I've been modifying a webpage that has HTML/CSS buttons that calls on Javascript functions to generate text in a text box and I read about jQuery could make more functional dialog boxes than the simple JS 'prompt'.

So essentially what I'm trying to do is have the following html

```
            <td><input class="button" onclick="p1();" type="button" value="STB Froze/Slow/Resetting"></td>
```

call on this jQuery script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
function p1()
$("#dialog").dialog({
    
    autoOpen: true,
    buttons: {
    
        Frozen: function() { 
    
            var newtext = "STB FROZEN, ";
            document.form1.textTarget.value += newtext;
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        },
        Slow: function() { 
            
            var newtext = "STB RUNNING SLOW, ";
            document.form1.textTarget.value += newtext;
            $(this).dialog("close"); 

        },
        Resetting: function() { 
            
            var newtext = "STB RESETTING, ";
            document.form1.textTarget.value += newtext;
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        }
    
    },
    width: "400px"
    
});

</script>
```

Sorry the code formatting looks like garbage... maybe thats my problem. But I don't get any errors in Visual Studio Code but I do when I try run in Edge or Chrome:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: p1 is not defined
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick (acctnotesvr_ALPHAv0.2.2 12312020.html:308) onclick @ acctnotesvr_ALPHAv0.2.2 12312020.html:308

Where 308 is the first line referenced above.

All I would like to do is when I click the HTML button in the first line of code above, a proper dialog box pops up letting me choose between 'frozen', 'slow', or 'resetting' and then generate the right output in a text box.

I can share my source HTML and my modified HTML file that I'm having this issue with but I must warn you my modified file is a huge mess since I'm really just tweaking someone else's work (with permission of course).

Thank you to anyone who can help me clear this up.

**EDIT:** Currently I have the first line of code listed above calling on the following Javascript function to generate a prompt. I feel a true button based dialog box will be simpler for a end user to operate with than a open field prompt.

```
function p1() {
var newtext = "STB ";
var stbiss = prompt('Is the STB Frozen, Slow, or Resetting?: ', '');
var comma = ", ";
document.form1.textTarget.value += newtext;
document.form1.textTarget.value += stbiss;
document.form1.textTarget.value += comma;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
So I implemented all the code corrections and additions provided by D. Seah (THANK YOU SO MUCH!) except for the following:

```
<form id="form1">
  <input id="textTarget" s̶t̶y̶l̶e̶=̶"̶w̶i̶d̶t̶h̶:̶ ̶5̶0̶0̶p̶x̶"̶ > <!-- striked through text not need due to the following-->
```

Because "textTarget" for the output textbox after the completes is being declared like so:

```
<div id="notes" valign="top">
<table border="1" id="notetable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="tr" colspan="2" id="coshead">Notepad</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="notecol" width="377"><textarea class="textTarget" name="textTarget"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="188px"><input class="button1" onclick="clearContents();" style="width:100%" type="button" value="Clear Notes"></td>
            <td class="tooltip" width="188px"><input class="button1" onclick="copyclipboard();" style="width:100%" type="button" value="Copy To Clipboard" onmouseout="outFunc()">
                <span class="tooltiptext" id="copyClip">Copy to Clipboard</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

So with that in mind and the addition of D. Seah's

```
function p1() {
    const update_text = (val) => {
      const input = $("#form1 #textTarget");
      if (input.val()) {
        input.val([input.val(), val].join(", "))
      } else {
        input.val(val)
      }
    }
```

I get the dialog box and the buttons but clicking on, for example, 'Frozen' doesn't output text to the "textTarget", but all my other HTML buttons that call on pure Javascript functions (example in the first EDIT) work as designed. Is there anyway to modify the 'const input=' or the 'class="textTarget"' to have the jQuery script output properly while maintaining the functionality of all my HTML/Javascript buttons?

Comment: assuming you're referencing your javascript file somewhere in (preferably bottom of) the html page. have you tried putting the javascript code in the html page within script tags? <script>function p3() { ...all your stuff here...}</script> ?

Comment: how does you #dialog html looks like?

Comment: Yes, I have the code within script tags. I should have included that above, will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you move forward

```js
function p1() {
  const update_text = (val) => {
const input = $("#form1 textarea[name='textTarget']");
if (input.val()) {
  input.val([input.val(), val].join(", "))
} else {
  input.val(val)
}
  }
  $("#dialog").dialog({

autoOpen: true,
buttons: {
  Frozen: function() {
    update_text("STB FROZEN")
    $(this).dialog("close");
  },
  Slow: function() {
    update_text("STB RUNNING SLOW")
    $(this).dialog("close");
  },
  Resetting: function() {
    update_text("STB RESETTING")
    $(this).dialog("close");
  }
},
width: "400px"
  });
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1">
<textarea name="textTarget" class="textTarget" cols=50 rows=5></textarea>
  </form>
  <table>
<tr>
  <td><input class="button" onclick="p1();" type="button" value="STB Froze/Slow/Resetting"></td>
</tr>
  </table>
  <div id="dialog"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `p1` function is defined in the jQuery ready closure and will not be available to the click target of running the function

**Your broken example**

- `p1` in closure, reference attempted outside closure

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

function p1() {
  console.log("button clicked handled by p1")
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=mybutton class=button onclick="p1();" type=button value="Test"/>
```

**Correct example**

- click handler installed inside closure where `p1` is also defined

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#mybutton").click(p1);  // p1 accessible before function p1 source code because functions are 'hoisted'

  function p1() {
    console.log("button clicked handled by p1")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=mybutton class=button type=button value="Test"/>
```